# How can I enable text compression in Gen4 VPS Linux 4 CPU

Tags: wordpress, google-pagespeed, text-compression

I have a server Gen4 VPS Linux 4 CPU where I have website called https://www.academiaerp.com/ and https://www.academiaerp.com/staging/. I was checking website speed using page speed insights and GTmetrix both of them mentioned I need to enabled text compression for better speed results.

I have contacted the godaddy support team to find solution for the issue and they said they can’t provide support for this.

I have tried using plugins and adding code in the htaccess files as well still it did not resolved as well,

Anyone happened to have solve this issue really it will be appreciated.

Screenshot : [https://pasteboard.co/QU9uIM5cS7zi.png[enter](https://pasteboard.co/QU9uIM5cS7zi.png%5Benter) image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Djq85.png)

I tried everything including adding the code to htaccess files but didnt work. I am not sure how can i enable it. I have asked the hosting provider but they said they dont have proper support.